# pip install error: RuntimeError: Unsupported compiler -- at least C++11 support is needed

Tags: pip, nmslib

I am trying to install pyserini, and it stuck at collecting nmslib>=2.1.1
[error message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1jqv.png)
It's previous issue is
clang: error: the clang compiler does not support '-march=native'
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
which I resolved by changing to clang 14.0.0
However, there is an new issue with Unsupported compiler.
Is there anyway to solve this?

I tried method from https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/issues/1196
with apt-get install build-essential -y
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
None of them worked

Comment: I have the same problem on Windows Subsystem for Linux trying to install some other non-official python module. I hope you'll get a solution!

Answer (score 1):

Aha! I had the same problem, tried out the last suggestion from the [github link](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/issues/1196) you posted:

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```

this apparently installs a C++ compiler...
And it worked for me!

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I met this problem and solved it by install 'gcc' and 'gcc-c++' like `microdnf install -y gcc gcc-c++` and then pip3 reinstalling the lib successfully.